# Play live URL streaming by AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avplayer

```
MY Real URL => "http://125.209.70.43:1500/"
```

As my title said that I want to play music from my live streaming `URL`. I tried with following code. *(following `URL` is for testing not real)*

```
[self playSelectedSong:@"http://media-ice.musicradio.com/HeartPlymouthV1"]; // custom method  with testing URL
```

Code of method.

```
-(void)playSelectedSong:(NSString *) urlString
{
   self.songPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];;
   [self.songPlayer play];
}
```

I have Question like.

**1)** What should proper `URL` Pattern? is streaming `URL` has any rules about its pattern or not ?
For example above code is woking for streaming `URL` *(NOT mine url)* such like,

```
 1) http://108.178.57.196:11112/los40principales 
 2) http://media-ice.musicradio.com/HeartPlymouthV1
```

**BUT**  in my `URL` it is not working ***(for iOS Devices)***, my `URL` pattern is

```
    http://125.209.70.43:1500/
```

My streaming `URL` pattern looking like above.

Then how can I play music by using above `URL` ? My above code is not working for `http://125.209.70.43:1500/`. Anybody have issue related as a mine ?
Please help me on this issue.

> **NOTE:** My URL is correct and its working, I checked with vlc media player network streaming. by

```
=> VLC Medial Player
    -> File Menu
       -> Open Network
          -> URL set as "http://125.209.70.43:1500/"
             -> click on "Open" button.
```

Try with above step it's working very well.

Answer (score 2):

Your stream is Windows Media Audio, that's not going to work with AVPlayer. If you want to support streaming to iOS devices, check out `https://developer.apple.com/streaming/`